# Login check android with sharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Goodday, I'm trying to create a login and logout with my app. Here is what i do, In my `login activity`i add this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

    String Username = new SessionHandler().getUsername(this);
        if(!Username.toString().equals("")){
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Login_activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
}
```

and here is my `SessionHandler().getUsername()`

```
  public String getUsername(Context context){
        sess_content = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        Username = sess_content.getString("Username", null); //2
        return Username;
    }
```

So, here is the problem when i already login i can pass the `login activity` and open `main activity` but when i logout then trying to open my app again . I get an error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.boby.helpdesk/com.example.boby.helpdesk.Login_activity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

this is how i set my `SharedPreferences`

```
public  void setSession(String name,String notelp,String alamat,String deskripsi,Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("Username", name);
    editor.putString("NoTelp", notelp);
    editor.putString("Alamat", alamat);
    editor.putString("Deskripsi", deskripsi);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code in `onCreate` method to below

```
String Username = new SessionHandler().getUsername(this);
        if(Username != null && !Username.isEmpty()){
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Login_activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change null to empty or as @rajan ks:

```
public String getUsername(Context context){
        sess_content = context.getSharedPreferences("LoginInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        Username = sess_content.getString("Username", ""); //2
        return Username;
    }
```